# how to get list all supported voices from Text To Speech in android studio

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I am working on TTS (Text to Speech). And I want to get the list of supported voices, what should I do
EXAMPLE:

```
private TextToSpeech t1;
t1 = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
      if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    t1.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                }
            }
      });
t1.setLanguage(Locale.US);
Voice va=new Voice("en-gb-x-rjs#female_2-local",new
Locale("en","US"),400,200,true,a);

t1.setVoice(va);
String toSpeak = textTitle.getText().toString();
t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

I want have all list as

> "en-gb-x-rjs#female_2-local"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech#getVoices())

`getVoices()` method from `TextToSpeech` returns set of all the available voices.

Comment: I already try but I just get null value

Comment: make sure you called it after TextToSpeed got initialized . i.e., after `onInit()`

Comment: also worth noting that there is also `isLanguageAvailable` method (theoretically `Locale.US` may not be present)

Comment: i have another problem as getVoices() = null when i call outside onInit(). I just get value when I call it in onInit(); Here my code: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FGzfp8SnSg/

Comment: Yes it is asynchronous. Do something like this https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3GxPCT9XVC/